# Output XML with same attribute into multiple rows in CSV file using XSLT

Tags: csv, xslt

I have XML with same attribute but different values.  Every different value should be output as a row in the CSV output file using XSLT. Below is the XML. For every field that peci:priorValue, I need to output  Prior value and current value in rows in CSV file.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-12-12T00:00:00.000-08:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-12-14T05:32:34.114-08:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2022-08-01-07:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2022-08-01-07:00</peci:Hire_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Compensation peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Position_ID>xyz</peci:Position_ID>
                <peci:Compensation_Grade>Salary</peci:Compensation_Grade>
                <peci:Compensation_Change_Reason peci:priorValue="Change_Location">COLA</peci:Compensation_Change_Reason>
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Annualized_Frequency peci:isUpdated="1">
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay peci:priorValue="8000">12000</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Currency>USD</peci:Currency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Annualized_Frequency>
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

My output should be

```
John Doe, Change_Location, COLA
John Doe, 8000, 12000
```

How can this be achieved? I am new to XSLT and so struggling with this.

I am getting an output like this

```
John Doe, Change_Location 8000, COLA 12000
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) your current XSLT and (2) the expected output.

Comment: Where's `John Doe` in the data???

Comment: You can apply template to attribute : <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> for example  or @attr1|@attr2…